# Managing large files (lines of code)

Tags: android, design-patterns

What techniques do you use to keep files from getting too large?
What refactorings do you use to break down large files?

I find that some files in my Android project get very large simply by the nature of the language and platform. For example, my main activity sets up an action bar, a drawer, options menu, and a click listener for each. Of course, that file also implements several inherited methods... next thing you know, the file ends on line 1500.

Since everything I'm bringing up to that file needs to be a concrete implementation, I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how I could abstract some of the stuff in it away from the file.

One thing I have tried is to separate some of the private inner classes into an Impl class, only so each file is smaller and more manageable:

```
// Instead of putting this inside MainActivity.java
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
{
    ...
}

// It's now in a separate file as - very specific class
public class DrawerItemClickListenerImpl implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
{
    ...
}
```

While this helps to break down the size of the one file, it feels weird creating classes that are only used once, and for a very specific reason...

Comment: Its a a nightmare, i agree. That's one of the hard facts of android programming.

Comment: IDE's features (folding, navigator) helps a lot to keep overview over long source code. And then you can use as much helper classes as you want (with package access level) to refactor code out of the "main" class.

Comment: Code folding and other IDE specific features help, but don't solve the problem. I still need to have a very complex mental picture of the file when working with it, so it would be better if there were less code to look at, not more ways to hide the code temporarily.

Comment: Hate to say this but moving a class from one place to another does not reduce the complexity. In other words, just because it's now in its own file you still need to know how it works if you're going to be debugging interactions between two classes.

Comment: True, but if a file says something like drawerLinks.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListenerImpl()); that's pretty easy to wrap one's head around, and it's easy to look at, read, and understand what is going on. If instead that statement includes the actual implementation of that class, even if the code can be folded, the file now has a lot more code that needs to be read and looked at, thus making it more complex to a developer just browsing through the file, for example...

Comment: Edited my post. Hope you can see my question now...

Comment: What's up with the down votes??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really **the nature of UI programing** and it is no different than java swing programming.

In that paradigm, you have a JPanel, with some buttons, some combo boxes and some listeners. You have to implement listeners to those elements but only that JPanel really has use for them. So, you implement inner classes as listeners so everything on that panel interacts well.

Having something like

```
public class IpAddressPanelListener implements ActionListener
```

as a public class misses the whole point. Public classes are about sharing usability. Inner classes are about classes that are super-specific to the job. Which, in the case of a UI is generally what you have

if you really need to break them out cause you can't conceptualize it all then what you could do is put them (and the Activity Class impl) into their own package and declare all classes and methods as **package scope**. Now you can have your files broken out without making them available to the general public

Answer (score 1):

One good Android design pattern is to use fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

At a very high level, fragments are classes for re-usable components in your Android application.  Fragments also offer other benefits.  One of the most notable is the ability to build adaptive UIs - that is UIs that make the best use of available screen real estate.  When you design your app with fragments, the role of your activity becomes the management of these fragments (e.g. providing data, interrogating them for user input, etc).

There are many good tutorials for fragment design out there.

Comment: I am using fragments. That doesn't influence my scenario very much because i still need to write code to launch and manage the fragments. As noted by +ChristianBongiorno the issue is more about UI programming than managing activities.

Comment: 1500 lines of code in an activity that simply manages fragments sounds excessive.  Most all of your UI concerns should be contained within your fragments.  FWIW, I noticed a significant reductions in the size/complexity of my activity classes when I started using fragments.

Comment: The 1500 loc don't simply manage fragments. It manages everything mentioned in my original post - action bar, drawer, activity methods, and everything else you'd expect from a launcher activity. What I meant to say was that in spite of my using fragments, the problem described in my post still exists.